Blacklisting from employment
Is blacklisted from jobs really a thing. I feel like my name is in a database online that shows do not hire or has negative notes about me.
I work for the school system and it seems whenever I apply for a job and I use my real name I automatically get rejected if I was to similar name of mines then I do get call back.
I also notice what ever job I get it happens. I have to use a similar name of mines just to get a call back or an interview. I feel like that my name is on a list for only HR personnel and supervisors to see on this database. It makes it very difficult to get or retain a job. I feel like whatever job I go to apply for, every HR Personnel, recruiters, and hiring managers see my name they automatically rejected me. For the school system I’m on this DNH list for every HR to see. I’m being blackballed and blacklisted and I’m just trying to figure out what to do

Why don't you look up your name online?

Schools are one of the cases where you may legitimately be on a list of people not considered safe around kids. But it that was true you should know about it. You may need to consider whether there are other professions where your skills would be useful.

Constructive discharge & resign on not so good terms.

Nobody gets blacklisted just for resigning, especially if as you claim  they wanted you to resign. On the other hand nobody who resigns on bad terms gets a good recommendation.

A country tag would be useful, employment law around  education(and health-care) are often different than general employment, and different for each country.

1 United States

Are you saying you think that the one school district is blacklisting you from jobs at various schools within it?  That is entirely likely, organizations usually mark people departing as “eligible for rehire” or not based on how it went down.  If you think there is a larger blacklist, there is not.

Why is this tagged "whistle-blowing"?  Were you a whistle-blower?

You stated, "It makes it very difficult to get or retain a job." Were you let go from a position, can you clarify what the position was and why you were let go? Also, has it happened once or multiple times?

Government Blacklists
You mentioning working for a school system, which yes there are blacklists for that field, but they are managed by government institutions or agencies.  These blacklists are intended to prevent people who have committed certain crimes, or deemed to be a high risk for certain crimes from working with children or vulnerable adults.  Typically people do not end up on one of these lists without knowing about it, since law enforcement would be involved.
Without a country tag I cannot tell you if you live in a country that has one (or more) of these types of lists nor which government agency is responsible for managing it, nor if you are able to access it directly yourself to see if you are on said list.
Mistaken Identity
It is possible that with how the schools are searching their government's registry that they are getting a bad match with someone else who has a similar or identical name as you.  Determining if this is the case can be easy if there is public access to your country's list, since all you would have to do is search it with your name and see if you get a match.  However, it might not be public and you would have to file a request with said agency and wait who knows how long for a response that might be useless.
If you do confirm that there is someone else with your name registered or if they incorrectly put you on the list when it should have been someone else you would need to work with that government agency and likely hire a lawyer who can help you navigate the process to get it cleaned up.
Search the Internet for Your Name
When all else fails throw your name into Google's or your preferred search engine and see what comes up.  If one of the first results is something that is not very flattering (even if it is for someone else who you happen to share a name with), then that is likely something the school systems reviewing your resume are also seeing, and might be the actual reason you keep getting immediately tossed out.
As for fixing those public relation (PR) problems, if you are in Europe you can try using the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) to exercise your Right to be Forgotten to have those stories removed or edited to no longer reference you by name, but you will want to consult with a lawyer to see if  it applies to you and said story, and what exactly your options are.

FWIW, trying to get a story or web page removed because your name is in it could be hard because the story/web page may be perfectly accurate about someone else with the same name, so technically there is nothing wrong with the info.  You would need to demonstrate there is inaccurate info that points at you instead of the other person.

Government Blacklists
The person who wrote this you may be exactly right. Can you explain more about this. Im located in the US and for years now weird things been going on around me. I have never committed any crimes the only thing that I did is complain about being treated unfairly at work and quit jobs because of it

@jano24 The big one for the US would be the National Sex Offender Registry, which also includes state level registries: https://www.nsopw.gov/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 Note that the school systems in your area could be using a background check service that runs your name against other smaller government systems which there would be no way to know which service they are using or what systems they are finding a match in.

Ok so do you think the government blacklist could apply to me because every time I apply for a job and they see my real full name, I'm automatically rejected and that is not just the school system it is for any job apply for. If I use a similar name to my real name I get call back and interviews and I get job offer of course I have to use my real name for the background check and paperwork, but as soon they find out my real name the job offer get rescinded. Everything is calm and collective if I use a similar name to my real name. This is frustrating every time I apply for jobs I get blacklist

Private companies and institutions do have internal blacklists but they typically don't share them and there is no online data base unless you work in a field that requires it.
More likely is that you have either issues with your resume, the way you present yourself and/or your Google or social media footprint. Take a look at those, or, better, have someone knowledgeable review those with you.

Let’s say if I know I’m on this internal blacklist what steps can I take to try and fix it?

There have been cases discovered of secret blacklist databases shared amongst companies in an industry.

Ok so what do you think I can do to get of this blacklist, because you are right there is a blacklist database shared with other companies so how can I stop it and who can I talk to about it?

If there is an internal blacklist, you can't fix it. Look for a job elsewhere.

@jano24 - If an employer has decided that you are NOT a good fit for them, there is absolutely nothing you can do, if you submit your resume to them and they choose NOT to interview you. You would have to prove the reason they choose to do this was for a protected reason rather than their determination that you are not qualified for the job. They probably will never tell you the reason they are NOT selecting you for the position.

@jano24. I repeat: the likelihood that you are on a shared blacklist is very low. Too much focus on that will prevent you from fixing the real root cause of whatever problem you are having (which you haven't shared yet). In case you really ARE on a blacklist: this depends a lot on what you did to get on there. Getting blacklisted typically happens as the result of an egregious offense. You should definitely avoid doing again whatever you did to get on there.

@jano24, Also, google yourself and search yourself on LexisNexis (go to the nearest public law school with a library). If someone has a similar name to yours, that's another reason you could be blacklisted. Also, people have informal networks. Looking at your LinkedIn, they could see who is connected to you, and if they personally know that contact, they could be giving them a quick phone call.

If you want to continue to work in education, there are places other than the school systems where you can work. In the US, many companies run training departments and hire educators. You don't have to keep "beating your head against a wall." Seek out other places where you can work.

Since no one here has mentioned this, you might want to consider if your name is "ethnic sounding".  There is much documentation that applicants with White-sounding names get lots more callbacks.  I've noted over my career that some of my colleagues from non-White ethnic groups choose to present with a Westernized, White-sounding name instead of their given name.
It's illegal to discriminate in the US, but hard to stop.  I feel for people whose parents have doomed them with such names.  If you fall in this group, consider using your initials or a nickname on your resume, as my colleagues do, and put your real name only on the job application.
This sucks, but it's a real thing.
